# Which shell do VS Code extensions use?

Tags: windows, shell, visual-studio-code, clang

[here](https://github.com/notskm/vscode-clang-tidy/issues/25),I got the problem that the same command run in the Windows CMD as run by the clang-tidy extension works for CMD but not in VS Code. Therefore I ask myself if (and if yes, which) another type of shell is used by VS Code and its extensions? Is this a extension problem or in any way Shell-related?

Comment: You need to add the PATHs to the gloval enviromental PATH variable, not only the one for your user. VS Code uses powershell by default in windows, but you can change it to any other shell by clicking where it says powershell in the "Terminal" part of the workspace, and clicking "Select default shell"

Comment: Both LLVM and MinGW are added to the user and global PATH variable